# submit (post or get) unreliable?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a select dropdown which triggers a function

```
<form action="visualise.jsp" name="myform" id="myform" method="get">                      
<select name="assettypeid" id="assettypeid" onchange="typechanged();">
      <sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
      SELECT id, name FROM assettype order by name
      </sql:query>
            <option value="1">-- All Asset Types--</option>
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${queryresults.rows}">
            <option value="<c:out value="${row.id}"/>"
            <c:if test="${row.id == param.assettypeid}">
            <c:out value="selected"/>
            </c:if>
            ><c:out value="${row.name}" />
            </option>
        </c:forEach>
        </select>
</form>       


function typechanged()
{       
   // Clear the timers to allow the submit to complete
   var noofTimeOuts = setTimeout('');
   for (var i = 0 ; i < noofTimeOuts ; i++) clearTimeout(i);

   typechosen = document.getElementById("assettypeid").value;
   alert(typechosen);

   myform.submit();

   // Delay to prevent resend messages from the browser
   setTimeout(window.location.reload(), 1000);      
}
```

The alert always fires but the submit does not send assettypeid occasionally, irrespective of whether I use post or get or enter any action in the form.

I have even allowed 'delays for the submit to occur' and stopped the refresh timers running on other functions but this makes no difference.

What am I missing?

Regards
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit confusing.  What does `visualise.jsp` do?  Isn't it returning the HTML for the page?

If it is, you'd just change your code to:

```
function typechanged() {
  document.getElementById('myform').submit();
}
```

The code to set/clearTimeout is wrong in several ways:

```
// This will call window.location.reload IMMEDIATELY
anyFunction(window.location.reload(), ...more arguments)
```

You need to wrap a `function() { ... }` around the code:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload() }, 1000);
```

I think you were also wanting to cancel a pending reload if user changed the `<select>` again?  If so, you need to save the returned value from `setTimeout` and use that in `clearTimeout`...  Try something like this:

```
function typechanged() {
  if (typechanged.timeout) {
    // Clear the timer to allow the submit to complete
    clearTimeout(typechanged.timeout);
    typechanged.timeout = null;
  }

  var typechosen = document.getElementById('assettypeid').value;
  alert(typechosen);

  myform.submit();

  // Delay to prevent resend messages from the browser
  typechanged.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks searlea, have made your changes but issue as before, the submit seems to 'fail' occasionally, do I have to create some sort of test to confirm it occurred and resubmit if failed? (visualise.jsp does post to itself)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'fail'?  If you know how to use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools, you can check if the form data is submitted to the server: then you might find that the problem isn't that the form fails to submit, but that the server fails to respond in less than 1 second, and therefore the page just reloads with the assettypeid already present in the current URL.

Comment: Hello searlea, fails to submit occasionally (no get or post seen in Firefox network analyser). There are web articles indicating that there are issues with onchange / post and a submit button (which submits without fail) should be used instead but I am trying to avoid that as a button always produces the silly resend messages in Firefox.

Comment: The resend message is what Firefox produces if you attempt to post to the same URL, even if the data is different. Post is preferred (as it doesn't append to the URL, as get does). The resend is not attempts to select a new dropdown value before the previous one has submitted.